kdb and python embedPy installation
I posted a similar question a few days ago regarding installing embedPy.
The documentation is here: https://github.com/KxSystems/embedpy and it's fairly simple to follow. I'm installing embedPy to run on my local machine by downloading and installing the latest release, 1.5.0.
There are 3 steps:

Downloading the release and unzipping
Run the tests q test.t
Put p.q and p.k in QHOME and the library file in $QHOME/{164,m64mw64}

To confirm I downloaded python v3.12, I ran the following:
q.p))system"where python3"
"C:\\Users\\a623\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python3.exe"
q.p))system"where python"
"C:\\Users\\a623\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe"
"C:\\Users\\a623\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\python.exe"

I'm on step 2, and I'm getting the strange error below:
M:\M\embedPy_windows-1.5.0>q test.q
KDB+ 4.0 2022.01.14 Copyright (C) 1993-2022 Kx Systems
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Loading custom startup.  Customize in C:/q/q.q
Start timestamp (local): 2024.04.01D09:36:01.173696000
Full display precisions: \P 0
C:/q/help.q
C:/q/c/odbc.k
C:/q/ps.k
'embedPy requires python 3.6 or higher on windows
  [5]  M:\M\embedPy_windows-1.5.0\p.q:10:
 c:"-c \"",pr["'.'.join([str(getattr(__import__('sys').version_info,x))for x in ['major','minor']])"],"\"2>",$[o="w";"nul <nul";"/dev/null"];
 if[(o="w")and `3.6>`$first@[system"python3 ",;c;{system"python ",c}];'"embedPy requires python 3.6 or higher on windows"];
                                                                       ^
 c:"-c \"",pr[$[o="w";sc["/python";`BINDIR`VERSION];sc["/libpython";`LIBDIR`LDVERSION]],"+'",$[o="w";".dll";o="l";".so";".dylib"],"'"],pr["__import__('sys').base_prefix"],pr["__import__('sys').prefix"],pr["__import__('sys').executable"],"\"2>",$[o="w";"nul <nul";"/dev/null"];

It's strange I'm getting this error because I do have python version 3.12. I'm wondering if anyone has any idea where the issue is and how to solve it?
Another question I have is how I can change the output of q.p))system"where python3" to be "C:\Users\a623\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe" instead, which is the first output of q.p))system"where python"
Any advice here is much appreciated, as I've been struggling a bit to get this to work.

embedPy 1.5.0 was released in Oct 2021 to support Python 3.9
The version check had a bug blocking >=3.10 being used.
It was fixed in this commit:
https://github.com/KxSystems/embedPy/commit/06d3039360a077a1d43ef44c8d70144a0b1dcb66
In p.q from:
 if[(o="w")and `3.6>`$first@[system"python3 ",;c;{system"python ",c}];'"embedPy requires python 3.6 or higher on windows"];

To:
 if[(o="w")and any 3 6>"J"$"." vs first@[system"python3 ",;c;{system"python ",c}];'"embedPy requires python 3.6 or higher on windows"];

You can edit your copy of p.q manually or you can build from source to get all updates/fixes since the last release:
https://github.com/KxSystems/embedPy?tab=readme-ov-file#clone-and-build-from-source
Going forward PyKX is the best interface between q and Python.
https://code.kx.com/pykx/2.4/pykx-under-q/intro.html
It is under active development and has official support up to Python 3.12.
https://code.kx.com/pykx/2.4/release-notes/changelog.html
